# Weard result in Qlikview

Tags: sql, reporting, qlikview, qliksense

I have a script in qlikview like this:

```
SQL select f.periode as PERIOD,
           f.turnover as turnover
 from tablename f;
```

In my result I see that i have like this below:

```
Period       turnover
              55555
              66666
              11111,00
              454.5456
201601
201509
201503
201605
```

I executed this sql statement in my database

I found :

```
Period   turnover
201601    55555
201509    66666
201503    11111.00
```

Your help is very appreciated, 
Thank you

Comment: Thats not weird, it just called null.

Comment: I forgot that notice that I executed this sql statement in my database and i found:  201601    555555

Comment: what DB are you using? try to without the "as"

Comment: I agree that it is quite strange. Where do you see the data displayed like that, is it in an object or on the table preview? And can you please show your entire load statement

Comment: Since the behaviour is not reproducible and due to a mistake not shown in the question I am voting to close this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it's weird i resolve it, the thing is i had a concatanation table, and I didn't add in my SQl statement the joins.

thank you all of you for your help